# iPhone dev - issue with @selector

Tags: iphone, selector

in my app I am trying to run some code that currently exists in my applicationWillTerminate in appDelegate.
I have c/p'd the same code into the method that is currently running (verified by NSLog), but the code just doesnt seem to execute the same way.

The following code is from my applicationWillTerminate, which saves data, ready for loading next time.

> [myArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(saveAllDataLeads)];

when I insert this into my DetailViewController.m (in a method that is currently active), I insert the following.

> [appDelegate.myArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(saveAllDataLeads)];

**The problem is that it just doesn't do the stuff in saveAllDataLeads, can someone see what is wrong? or is more information required.**

Regards

in DetailViewController.h i have declared

> MyAppDelegate *appDelegate;

Comment: I assume you also set the appDelegate in DetailViewController.m somewhere, right?

Comment: Did you check that your appDelegate is valid? You do not actually need to store delegate object as you can access it using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]

Comment: @Hutaffe, what extra type of declaration do you mean? I only have the one in the .h

Comment: If you never set appDelegate to point to the instance of MyAppDelegate created when your application launches, it will simply be nil.  A message to nil does nothing.

Comment: Declaring your reference to the AppDelegate is of course not enough, so either you set it somewhere (appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];) or you leave that reference and just use the delegate like Vladimir suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects that you have added to myArray must have a selector with no parameters, named saveAllDataLeads, that is:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {  
}  
- (void)saveAllDataLeads;  
@end  

@implementation MyObject
- (void)saveAllDataLeads {
  // do something
}
@end
```

Then, presumably somewhere you are adding instances of MyObject to myArray:

```
MyObject* instance = [MyObject new];
[appDelegate.myArray addObject:instance];
[instance release];
```